# How to use collect_list?

Tags: sql, scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two `DataFrame` and would like to join them according to `date`,`time`,`mid`,`binImbalance` fields and collect the corresponding values in `timeB` and `midB` in lists.

I have tried with the following code:

```
val d1: DataFrame
val d3: DataFrame
val d2 = d3
     .withColumnRenamed("date", "dateC")
     .withColumnRenamed("milliSec", "milliSecC")
     .withColumnRenamed("mid", "midC")
     .withColumnRenamed("time", "timeC")
     .withColumnRenamed("binImbalance", "binImbalanceC")

  d1.join(d2, d1("date") === d2("dateC") and 
              d1("time") === d2("timeC") and 
              d1("mid") === d2("midC")
         )
    .groupBy("date", "time", "mid", "binImbalance")
    .agg(collect_list("timeB"),collect_list("midB"))
```

But this does not work as I get the error: `: Reference 'timeB' is ambiguous, could be: timeB#16, timeB#35`.
At the same time, if I renamed one of the `timeB` column, I would not be able to collect the values in a list.

An example result should be:

```
+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+------+
| date|     time|   mid|binImbalance|    timeB|  midB|
+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+------+
|  1  |     1   |  10  |           1|    4    |  10  |          
|  2  |     2   |  20  |           2|    5    |  11  |            
|  3  |     3   |  30  |           3|    6    |  12  |             


+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+------+
| date|     time|   mid|binImbalance|    timeB|  midB|
+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+------+
|  1  |     1   |  10  |           1|    7    |  13  |          
|  2  |     2   |  20  |           2|    8    |  14  |            
|  3  |     3   |  30  |           3|    9    |  15  |
```

RESULT:

```
+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+-----------+
| date|     time|   mid|binImbalance| ListTime|  ListMid  |
+-----+---------+------+------------+---------+-----------+
|  1  |     1   |  10  |           1|   [4,7] |  [10,13]  |          
|  2  |     2   |  20  |           2|   [5,8] |  [11,14]  |            
|  3  |     3   |  30  |           3|   [6,9] |  [12,15]  |
```

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```
d1            d2
id   data     id   data    
--   ----     --   ----
1    1        1    2
2    4        2    5
3    6        3    3

Result
id   list
--   ----
1    [1,2]
2    [4,5]
3    [6,3]
```

Comment: Can you please add `d1.printSchema` and `d3.printSchema` to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Solution on the *minimal example*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val aggregateDataFrames = udf( (x: Double, y: Double) => Seq(x,y))

val d3 = d2.withColumnRenamed("id","id3")
           .withColumnRenamed("data","data3")

val joined = d1.join(d3, d1("id") === d3("id3"))


val result = joined
              .withColumn("list", aggregateDataFrames(joined("data"),joined("data3")))
              .select("id","list")
```

Comment: You may want to use `val aggregateDataFrames: (Double, Double) => Seq[Double]` and leave the types out in `udf`. Also, use `'` (a single apostrophe) to access columns (or `$` (dollar sign)) as it cuts few more keystrokes (and you may actually like it better).